# "google_trans_new" Python Library giving "Extra data" error

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

I was using VSCode to write Python code. When running the code in debug mode it gives the following error:

`Extra data: line 1 column 390 (char 389)
File "---" line 20, in  translated_text = translator.translate(speech_text, lang_tgt = 'fr')`

Some code that runs the same issue can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEEmw.png).

The line in question is the following:
`translated_text = translator.translate(speech_text, lang_tgt = 'fr')`

I have imported the library into VS Code and am using the right Python version. Does anyone know a fix to this error? Has the documentation changed?

Comment: Please go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and provide required code for debugging/fixing.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have run across the [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/lushan88a/google_trans_new/issues/36) of google_trans_new, this is the workaround:

> Change the line 151 in google_trans_new/google_trans_new.py which is:
> response = (decoded_line + ']') to response = decoded_line